# why everyone wants NOSQL other than large-scale Oracle Clusters?

Tags: database, oracle, nosql, oodb

oracle has a good reputation for handling large-scale applications and it's also flexible to extend to cluster environment. Why everyone wants NOSQL?

because nosql db is much cheaper?
why not swith object-oriented db?

Comment: Last time I checked, Oracle priced *per core* - not cheap.

Comment: Object-oriented databases, NoSQL and Oracle all specialize in different use cases.

Comment: Oracle Standard Edition is per socket, Enterprise Edition (and options) are per core.

Comment: Isn't an OODB an *instance* of NoSQL?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, not everyone does want NoSQL. Packaged software (eg ERP) is all pretty much mainstream RDBMS stuff. Don't confuse the amount of development effort with the usage.

What has happened is that NoSQL has opened up a whole range of applications that simply didn't suit relational technologies, and so there's been a rush of applications that CAN be developed. Most of the stuff that could be developed on RDBMS platforms already has been and is in more of a maintenance/upgrade phase. Probably with less upgrading than usual because of the whole global financial climate.

So in ten/fifteen years, as those NoSQL apps move into the same level of maturity, the frenzy will have died down and there's be less excitement.

Comment: "Don't confuse the amount of development effort with the usage." Or the amount of hype, press coverage, blog posts ...

Answer (score 1):

Oracle also have NoSQL solution: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/nosqldb/overview/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A SQL solution isn't necessarily what you want regardless of scale.
There are situations where you can't easily predict the schema of your model, or worst still your data is schemaless. In those situations you want a data model which doesn't limit you but rather allows you the flexibilty you need to evolve your data while still maintaining core abilities such as fast indexes.

Another reason is that SQL doesn't represent the natural way in which you want to look at your data, predominantly graph DBs such as Neo4J or GraphDB allow developers or users to approach a linked graph model in a more intuitive way.

Of course there is a way to address all these issues in Oracle RDBMS, but it feels more like hacking the DB to fit your needs as opposed to using a DB that fits you. This sounds like a perk but it actually goes a long way into the ease of development and analysis of your application.

Now if we are talking about scale, Oracle can probably beat column based DBs such as HBase or Hypertable, but it is important to note that Oracle RDBMS isn't just more expensive it's way way more expensive. In today's world even small time startups have Terabytes of data they need to analyze daily. Even small companies can use clusters of 100 machines in the cloud to store their data, in such a company Oracle isn't a viable option the annual licensing cost and the hiring of DBAs will prevent startups from using it.

Finally the last reason why you would start off with NoSQL is speed, bringing up a MongoDB and starting development can be done in 5 minutes and sometimes you wanna handle problems as they come up and avoid premature optimization

Comment: what about OODB~
i don't think nosql db will last long as they don't really reduce the resistance between database and oop.
if we ultimately need a pure oodb, using nosql as a solution to extend our db seems unwise?

Comment: you might be right, maybe OODB is the future, but for many real world scenarios NoSQL is the present.
I'm pretty sure programming languages will look completely different 10 years from now, however, I would still build a project with Java before I will build it in Go (The google programming language)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to let go consistency, there are no theorical limits to how mouch you can scale out some NoSQL solutions.

Some RDBMS can scale a lot, and Oracle is among the best of them, but no RDBMS let you cut in consistency, and therefor even the best has a pretty clear theorical limit to how much it can scale, not to mention the real world limits.

Some big names on the net just can't rely only on RDBMS anymore, and many others follows just to be like the big ones. Finally, some solutions are realy best fitted on a scheam-less structure, but those don't account for the most part of NoSQL users I would guess. The main point is to scale the web 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general question you are asking.  Are you comparing the relational database to NOSQL database, or are you comparing commercial or open source database?  We need to figure out as it seems we are comparing apples to oranges, and you will not get a straight answer.

Here are the breakdown from my perspective.

DB type: If you are comparing relational db vs NOSQL db, you should refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559411/sql-mysql-vs-nosql-couchdb)
instead.

Cost: If you are comparing from a cost perspective, each has its own cost.  Oracle will charge for the license, while the NOSQL db (using MongoDB as an example) are open source, and you don't have to pay the license.  But you will need someone to have a good understanding of NOSQL to administer and maintain the site, which is a lot harder to find.

Application: What kind of application are you writing?  You need to understand the database requirement for your application.  If you need to store a lot of unstructured data as a key value entry, you are better off using NOSQL.  On the other side of coin, you would prefer SQL db if you will join a lot of tables and execute complex SQL.

You mentioned Object Oriented DB, and that is another type of database from NoSQL or relational DB. At the end, it depends on your need.  To expand the choice of horizon, some might heard of hierarchical database, which mainly live in mainframe environment.  :-)