# nosql vs relational database

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, t-sql, nosql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NoSql vs Relational database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160732/nosql-vs-relational-database)

Hello Gurus

I am a SQL-Server developer + Development DBA (Production DBA is managed by our hosting partner)

While i was surfing the web, I came across NoSQL article (Link below). Is this something relational database guys has to be concerned about? I am concerned on what future holds for SQL-Developers and SQL-server DBAs

Any thoughts gurus?

http://techblog.netflix.com/2011/01/nosql-at-netflix.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

Cheers

Comment: There are many related questions.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160732/nosql-vs-relational-database

Comment: What is your question? StackOverflow is not intended for discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Concerned?  No, unless you intend to know SQL for a particular vendor and learn nothing else for the rest of your life.

"NoSQL" isn't intended as a pejorative against SQL or relational databases.  It's short for "Not Only SQL."  It says that not all persistent data problems are relational.

Analysis of terabyte or petabyte sized data sets might not belong in a single relational instance.  New tools will be needed.

Change is good.