# Comparison of mongodb with table-based db

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database, nosql

I try to understand which problems are better to solve with mongodb. Maybe someone can provide link to some article about where it's better to use mongodb and where it's better to use table-based DBs.

thank you in advance!

Comment: possibly an already answered question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160732/nosql-vs-relational-database

Comment: click on 'mongodb' tag here and order by votes ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has a short document [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Use+Cases).

There is also a list of [production deployments](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Deployments). That should provide some ideas of who is using MongODB.