# What are the advantages of MongoDB over MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, nosql

i've been thinking to use MongoDB for my next project (python), but for now, i don't understand which are the advantages of use NoSQL MongoDB against SQL.

Can you give some ideas or reasons of why to use NoSQL MongoDB?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no *best reason*. The title makes your question very subjective. *What are the advantages of MongoDB over MySQL and PostgreSQL?* would be a better fit for Stackoverflow's Q&A format.

Comment: ok, i think i'm going to change the question. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoSql vs Relational database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160732/nosql-vs-relational-database)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this presentation there are some great points about using Mongodb [link](http://www.slideshare.net/jnunemaker/why-mongodb-is-awesome)

Answer (score 0):

Since MongoDB is a document oriented database like RavenDB maybe the following can give you an idea:

> The schema-less nature makes it ideal to store dynamic data, such as
>   CMS and CRM entities, which the end user can usually customize as
>   necessary or semi structure data (provided by human). On top of that,
>   Raven offers a powerful indexing mechanism, allowing you to define a
>   Linq query as an index. Raven will take that query and execute it in
>   the background, the result of that Linq query is immediately available
>   as a view that you can query upon. We see Raven as appropriate for:
>
> 1. Web Related Data, such as user sessions, shopping cart, etc. - Raven's
>      document based nature means that you can retrieve and store all the
>      data required to process a request in a single remote call.
> 2. Dynamic Entities, such as user-customizable entities, entities with a large
>      number of optional fields, etc. - Raven's schema free nature means
>      that you don't have to fight a relational model to implement it.
> 3. Persisted View Models - Instead of recreating the view model from
>      scratch on every request, you can store it in its final form in Raven.
>      That leads to reduced computation, reduced number of remote calls and
>      improved overall performance.
> 4. Large Data Sets - The underlying storage
>      mechanism for Raven is known to scale in excess of 1 terabyte (on a
>      single machine) and the non relational nature of the database makes it
>      trivial to shard the database across multiple machines, something that
>      Raven can do natively.

From: http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-what-is-raven