# What situations is MongoDB perfect for?

Tags: mongodb

Scenario building a basic auto-complete for a search bar and Mongo seems to be the answer for both the auto complete and the search results, In the past I would use backbone for auto complete and the search results would be a List from Linq-sql

I'm looking for speed and Mongo seems to be key here, however MongoDB seems to have allot more cons than pro's

### To the point:

- Is there a situation where MongoDB looks like it was made to solve that problem?
- Is sacrificing Features worth the speed?(How much faster?) and cost?(Hosting)
- MongoDB is great, I guess to see the bigger picture of No-Sql over RDMS ill have to see a good scenario

Comment: This question will raise heavily opinion based answers, is too broad (both unacceptable according to the rules) and Stackoverflow is the wrong place to ask it, since SO is aimed at _programming_ questions. You might better ask it on http://dba.stackexchange.com .

Comment: There a tons of questions similar already. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160732/nosql-vs-relational-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to mention the strong and weak sides of mongodb.

**Strong**

1. Document (row in terms of SQL) can have any struct (schema) within
   one collection (table in terms of SQL)
2. Easy to [horizontal scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Horizontal_and_vertical_scaling) your database using [sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/)
3. Good means for [replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/)
4. Good speed
5. Can store files using [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/)

**Weak**

1. No [joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)). So you can't manipulate data from different collections in one request.
2. No [transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). But manipulating with single document is atomic.
3. Size of one document is [limited to 16Mb](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) (**not** in GridFS).