# What is Big Data & What classifies as Big data?

Tags: ssis, data-mining, bigdata

I have went through a lot of articles but I dont seem to get a perfectly clear answer on what exactly a BIG DATA is. In one page I saw "any data which is bigger for your usage, is big data i.e. 100 MB is considered big data for your mailbox but not your hard disc". Whereas another article said "big data to be usually more than 1 TB with different volume / variety / velocity and couldn't be stored in a single system". Also that data should be stored in a NOSQL db with Hadoop used to transform data.

Further, I have been working on a solution and was wondering if I could classify it as a big data. Snippets on the solution below,

- Millions of raw data records and usually 500 plus GB of data.
- SQL database as back-end and SSIS / SQL queries to cleanse/process the data and convert it to       a meaningful form.
- Visualization using Spotfire

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Lets hear a couple of opinions and then vote for a closure, shall we?

Comment: From [help/dont-ask]: "_Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much._"

Answer (score 11):

Big data is huge and complex data , which is challenging to capture, store, process, retrieve and analyze it.

Four main characteristics:

1. **Volume** :  “big” word in big data talks for the sheer volume.  It could amount to hundreds of terabytes or even petabytes of information.
2. **Velocity**: Velocity means the rate at which data is growing.
3. **Variety** : Big Data could be in any form such as structured, unstructured, text, images, log files etc.
4. **Veracity**: Veracity refers to quality and accuracy of data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So big data isnt relative? Like the case I mentioned above? 100 mb is big data for mailbox and not hard disc?

Comment: 100 mb is not big data. I have updated my answer with more details now.

Comment: Thanks. And would my solution be classified as big data? I suppose it satisfies all the four V's but its stored in MS SQL and processed using SSIS. Does where we store and how we process matter?

Comment: It's not big data as variety has not been satisfied with MS-SQL server. It can store structured data only. Big data can store peta bytes of data including structured, un-structured and semi-structured including audio, video and images. MS-SQL does not fit here.

Comment: You can have 4000 data node cluster and you can do real time processing on huge sets of data

Comment: Have a look at this question to under stand nosql (to store big data)  vs rdbms : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160732/nosql-vs-relational-database

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look.

Answer (score 9):

Big data is:

When a **big boss** believes this is a **big opportunity** because data is the new oil and gold, and get a **big pile of money** to throw out a window and flush it down the bowels. And then your data warehouses and silos turn into a data lake and the data lake full of *synergy* into a data swamp full of bit rot; where the **big vision** hits the reality that not everything that shines is gold. And then the gates of doom open and there it comes, the **big bubble** that is about to burst. The bridge over the through of desillusionment is small, and thou shall not pass, but tumble into the **big abyss** where all useless data go, no latter how eagerly it was collected and mapped and reduced without plan or objective. Bingo!

Comment: hehehe ... a classic. Deserves an entry in the jargon file, right alongside the SNAFU principle!   "And the plan was without form, and the specification was void."

Comment: Best definition ever. Still #lmao

Comment: This definition is **bigly hilarious**.

Answer (score 4):

The Big Data Definitions & Taxonomies Subgroup of the [NIST Big Data Public Working Group](http://bigdatawg.nist.gov/V1_output_docs.php) released a volume on definitions [NIST Big Data Interoperability Framework: Volume 1, Definitions](http://bigdatawg.nist.gov/_uploadfiles/NIST.SP.1500-1.pdf)

Quotes:

> Big Data refers to the inability of traditional data architectures to
>   efficiently handle the new datasets. Characteristics of Big Data that
>   force new architectures are:
>
> - Volume (i.e., the size of the dataset);
> - Variety (i.e., data from multiple repositories, domains, or types);
> - Velocity (i.e., rate of flow); and
> - Variability (i.e., the change
>     in other characteristics).
>
> These characteristics—volume, variety,
>   velocity, and variability—are known colloquially as the ‘Vs’ of Big
>   Data

and:

> ***Big Data*** consists of extensive datasets—primarily in the characteristics of volume,
>   variety, velocity, and/or variability—that require a scalable architecture for efficient
>   storage, manipulation, and analysis.

Comment: To the V's of Big Data, you need to add it something more which is `Value`. Value is the V more important in Big Data and without it, none of the others are useful.