# Algorithm to Merge-Join Large files

Tags: algorithm, memory, join, merge, large-files

Assume that I've got four large files (too large to bring into memory even individually) that has information I need to process.  I intend to produce a single application level object (Record) from each line in file #1.  Files 2-4 each have additional pieces of information required to compose this Record object.  For example, the file structure may be as follows:

File #1:
**key, description**

File #2:
**key, metadata, size**

File #3:
**origin, rate, key**

File #4:
**key,  startDate,  endDate**

Each file has a single column (of known position within a line) that represents a unique key.  This key is shared across files, but there is no guarantee that each key that exists in any one file, exists in the others, meaning we'll only process the subset of keys that exist in all.  The rows of the files are not sorted.  Can you devise an algorithm to produce the app-level objects by processing these files?

Answer (score 2):

#### Using a key-value store database

Databases are the best tools to handle datasets larger than your memory. Put your files into a key-value store (NoSQL DB like CouchDB or Cassandra will be great). Solve your problem using key queries.

#### Using sort and binary search

If you can't use databases, sort your file according to the key column (this can be easily done using [GNU sort](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html)). Than you can access your files in `nlogn` time using the key. Iterate over the largest file, and process each record using calls to the other files. This way your disk reads are likely to ba cached.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping it wouldn't come to this.  And what if the key that's in the file is not the same key I use to store these Record objects in my NoSQL solution?  Assume I use another unique key (UUID) and they "key" in these files are only for recomposing these objects?

Comment: You can define the key string used in your NoSQL DB.

Comment: Just use the key string that is most convenient for you, or use multiple indices on the db. On another note, while NoSQL are certainly nice, I don't see any benefit over a plain SQL database in this particular application.

Comment: A key-to-value query might be way faster in NoSQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145726/what-is-nosql-how-does-it-work-and-what-benefits-does-it-provide/1145751#1145751

Answer (score 1):

You could dump everything into a database (actually, a plain SQL one would be fine), and then delete the "incomplete" records.

To do it file-wise, you can do this:

- Sort all files by the id key
- open all sorted files
- read the first record from each file
- if you don't have 4 "matching" records, discard the one with the lowest id until you do
- merge the 4 "matching" records
- rinse and repeat