# Full text search(Postgres) Vs Elastic search

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, indexing, full-text-search, object-oriented-database

Read [Query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/737275/3317808)

In Posgres, Full text indexing allows documents to be preprocessed and an index saved for later rapid searching. Preprocessing includes:

- Parsing documents into tokens.
- Converting tokens into lexemes.
- Storing preprocessed documents optimized for searching.

---

`tsvector` type is used in Postgres for full text search

`tsvector` type is different than `text` type in below aspects:

- Eliminates case. Upper/lower case letter are identical
- Removes stop words ( and, or, not, she, him, and hundreds of others)-because these words are not relevant for text search
- Replaces synonyms and takes word stems (`elephant` -> `eleph`). In the full text catalogue, it does not have the word `elephant` but the word `elep`.
- Can (and should) be indexed with GIST and GIN
- Custom ranking with weights & `ts_rank`

---

How Elastic search(search engine) has advantage over full text search in Postgres?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

fulltext search and elasticsearch are both built on the same basic technology **inverted indices** so performance is going to be about the same.

FTS is going to be easier to deploy.

ES comes with lucene,

if you want lucene with FTS that will require extra effort.

Comment: For full text search, apart from Postgres database setup, do we need anything else for deployment?

Comment: no other components re required, there is however quite a lot to read and understand before it can be used..

Comment: Major advantage could be Elastic carries NoSQL database where as PostGres is OODBMS... For example: For text search from multiple data sources.. gathering the data from multiple data sources to NoSQL makes more sense...

Comment: NoSQL does not add anything.

Comment: NoSQL gives flexibility in schema design

Comment: Collection of documents in NoSQL is different from bunch of tables in RDBMS, Isn't it?

Comment: documents are records, not tables.

Comment: My bad.. yes you are right.. the structure of each document can be different unlike table row... Isn't it?

Comment: yeah,  JSON documents (of mixed structure) can also be stored in the rows of postgresql tables. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-json.html

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17955601/3317808) talks about heterogenous data, where MongoDB is preferred over PostGreSQL

Comment: The single most important factor in designing the database schema with MongoDB is about, **matching the data access patterns** of your application. One [case-study](https://anton.dollmaier.name/storing-syslogs-mongodb-syslog-ng) where full-text search was slower in MySQL compared to MongoDB.

Comment: comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: ElasticSearch also uses NoSQL database.