# How to do quickly search with multiple string in postgreSQL in case of very large database?

Tags: postgresql, performance, text-search

I try to build a data search system with  around 9 million data for my supershop project.
So I need to search with multiple strings like product code, name, type etc. But when I search it took too much time to fetch data, also when I run the SQL it took more than two minutes to show the data.
Suggest me some way that I can reduce the execution time.

Comment: Use Lucene - or at least build a full-text index. Read the docs:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Full text search(Postgres) Vs Elastic search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879070/full-text-searchpostgres-vs-elastic-search)

Comment: All the people who don't live in India are not likely to know what a "lakh" (or "lac") is. Please don't use Indian words here.

Comment: @JamesZ "Please don't use Indian words here." - I'll charitably assume you meant "please don't use Indian words **exclusively** here" - I'm all for exposure to different cultural traits and idioms, I'm _not_ for the kind of culture erasure you could be taken for advocating... otherwise it's like insisting on only using Fahrenheit instead of Fahrenheit _in addition_ to Celsius.