# What is a "NoSQL" Database Model?

Tags: sql, database, nosql

According to https://www.mongodb.com/nosql-explained:

NoSQL database models are either:

> key-value pairs, document-based, graph databases, or wide-column
>   stores.

But according to [What is NoSQL, how does it work, and what benefits does it provide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145726/what-is-nosql-how-does-it-work-and-what-benefits-does-it-provide?noredirect=1&lq=1):

"NoSQL" is basically:

> "a generic word for a variety of new data storage backends that do not
>   follow the relational DB model."

This confuses me because there are many (a lot more than just the 4 listed on the MongoDB source) of database models that aren't listed like star schema, network model, etc. (found here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_model)

What am I missing?

Comment: Star schema within a relational SQL database is still relational SQL; the model used does not necessarily imply SQL or NoSQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen both relational model and star schema model are database models, but a relational database can use star schema? sorry i don't understand the point youre making

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some additional research and I'm not sure if I got it right but here's my attempt.

---

A NoSQL Database can be implemented with any non-relational Database Model.

The "NoSQL Database Types": "key-value pairs, document-based, graph databases, or wide-column stores" does not refer to a Database Model. It is referring to the particular data structures used.

**Example:** MongoDB is one of many NoSQL Databases and it is implemented with a Semi Structured Database Model and is a Document-Based type of NoSQL Database

(My interpretation of the first line in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB)